# How do I express Quantity values in different notations?

Tags: units, physical-constants

I am trying to obtain the value of physical constants such as speed of light $c = 2.998 \times 10^8\,\rm{m/s}$. But Mathematica doesnt seem to give me a direct answer. I have to do a round-about method using `UnitConvert` as shown below. How do I get it to express in different forms like engineering, scientific notations like $2.998 \times 10^8\,\rm{m/s}$?

No matter what wrapper I use, I seem to get the same output.

MWE:

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SpeedOfLight"],   "meters/sec"] // EngineeringForm
UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SpeedOfLight"],   "meters/sec"] // TraditionalForm
UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SpeedOfLight"],   "meters/sec"] // ScientificForm
```

Output:

```
299792458m/s
299792458m/s
299792458m/s
```

Comment: Use numerical values: e.g. `N @ UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SpeedOfLight"],   "meters/sec"] // EngineeringForm`. With integer input  `EngineeringForm` and `ScientificForm`  give the input back. (Because, for example [EngineeringForm](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EngineeringForm.html) _prints with all **real numbers** in expr given in engineering notation_ .) and `TraditionalForm`  just adds digit blocks in the formatting.

Comment: @kglr please see my comment to the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

kglr comment is one way to solve your problem, but it can also be solved by making sure you give `UnitConvert` a machine number in its 1st argument.

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[1., "SpeedOfLight"], "meters/sec"] // EngineeringForm
```

> `299.792*10^(6)m/s`

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[1., "SpeedOfLight"], "meters/sec"] // ScientificForm
```

> `2.99792*10^(8)m/s`

If you are going to do this sort of thing a lot, I recommend writing a custom function -- a very simple one, based on kglr's comment will do the job.

```
formatQuantity[value_, name_, unit_, formatter_] :=
  formatter[N[UnitConvert[Quantity[value, name], unit]]]
```

Then you can do

```
formatQuantity[1, "SpeedOfLight", "meters/sec", ScientificForm]
```

[image: c]

and

```
formatQuantity[1, "AstronomicalUnit", "meters", EngineeringForm]
```

[image: au]

Comment: I din't realize passing arguments as machine precision will make such a big difference. Should I start cultivating the habit of mentioning everything (except for iteration counters, and others that are meant to be int dtype) as float ?

Comment: @JohnHonai. No, in general that would be a bad habit. For numeric calculation one should consider whether exact numbers, arbitrary precision numbers or machine numbers should be used on case-by-case basis. In some cases, like this one, machine arithmetic is best, but only because forcing basic physical quantities to be expressed as machine numbers (they are stored as exact quantities, integers or rationals) is needed to get around what some might considered a quirk in front-end's display logic.